# de Rham cohomology of a double

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Recall a double of a manifold (with boundary) M is two copies of M with boundary glued together. Let me call it D. How can I calculate $H^*(D)$  from $H^*(M)$?

I know a trivial example is the double of a half plane (which is The Whole plane). What about some more complicated examples?

Comment: I am pretty sure the double of the Möbius strip is the Klein bottle, which is a nice example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $M_1$ and $M_2$ the two copies, and $U$ a tubular neighborhood of $\partial M$ in $D$, then apply Mayer-Vietoris to $A=M_1 \cup U$, $B=M_2 \cup U$, giving an exact long sequence $H^i(D) \rightarrow H^i(M_1 \cup U) \oplus H^i(M_2 \cup U)=H^i(M)^2 \rightarrow H^i(U)=H^i(\partial M) \rightarrow H^{i-1}(D)$.

Comment: Why $H^I(M\cup U)=H^I(M)$

Comment: Because you can retract $U \cap M_2$ on $\partial M$.

Comment: On $M$, my mistake.

Comment: I see. This comes from the definition of tubular neighborhood. Thanks.

Comment: Also I can use the same method to compute the connected sum, right?

Comment: You should be able to do it, yes, if you know the homology of $M$ minus a ball.